# queues remain unknown or just don't know how to call them

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I've added a new queue to a python GAE app, and would like to add tasks to it, but always get an `UnknownQueueError` when I run my tests. On the other hand, I see the queue present in the GAE admin console (both local and remote). So the question is (1) do I miss something when I add a task to my queue? (2) if not, then how can I run custom queues in a test?

Here is my queue.yaml

`queue:
- name: requests
  rate: 20/s
  bucket_size: 100
  retry_parameters:
    task_age_limit: 60s`

and my python call is the following:

`taskqueue.add(queue_name="requests", url=reverse('queue_request', kwargs={"ckey":ckey}))`

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If your are running a unitest and using init_taskqueue_stub() you need to pass the path of the queue.yaml when calling it using the root_path parameter.

Comment: I do so, I'm running django tests, and my setup includes

    self.testbed = testbed.Testbed()
    self.testbed.activate()
   self.testbed.init_taskqueue_stub(root_path=os.path.join(settings.PROJECT_ROOT, 'queue.yaml'))

Comment: @Akasha are you using init_taskqueue_stub?

Comment: In your case you would simply call... self.testbed.init_taskqueue_stub(root_path=settings.PROJECT_ROOT)